# Post not pulling in correct category WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, post

I apoligize if this has been answered elsewhere, but this is probably the most basic WordPress loop question, that I can't seem to figure out. I have a custom category on this page: http://goo.gl/J4FdhX towards the bottom in the middle column called "Jewelry." This area should be pulling a 'home-thumbnail' and 'the_excerpt' according to the below code. Am I overlooking something? Anything helps.

```
 <div class="six columns post-bg">
                                            <div class="post-bg-wrapper sameheight">
                                               <h2>JEWELRY</h2>
                                            <?php
                                            $args = array(
                                                'posts_per_page' => 1,
                                                'category' => 'jewelry',
                                            );

                                            // The Query
                                            $query = new WP_Query( $args );

                                            // The Loop
                                            if ( $query->have_posts('') ) {
                                                while ( $query->have_posts('') ) {
                                                    $query->the_post(); ?>
                                                    <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
                                                         <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail()) : ?>
                                                    <div class="center img">
                                                        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>" >
                                                           <?php the_post_thumbnail('home-thumbnail'); ?>
                                                        </a>
                                                    </div>
                                                         <?php endif; ?>
                                                    <p class="primary-link"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read More</a></p>
                                            <?php   }
                                            }
                                            wp_reset_postdata();
                                            ?>
                                             </div>
                                        </div>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I think You have just inserted an extra '' in have_posts() . Else It seems ok.

```
if ( $query->have_posts('') ) {
                                            while ( $query->have_posts('') )
```

If its not yet resolved that too.., let me know, will clarify & debug your code in detail

Comment: Here's what I'm seeing...if a post from any category is posted at a later date than the post which populates that center area, the loop is thrown off.

Comment: ok. But have you tried by removing those extra single quotes you have imparted in have_post('')... ???   Bcoz. it must have been like just :   if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
                                            while ( $query->have_posts() )